# When upgrading from asmx to wcf, does every member need to be decorated with the DataMember attribute?

Tags: wcf, asmx

I have a web service that is currently using asmx.  The operations are decorated with WebMethod and each takes in a request and returns a response.  I started creating a WCF app and I am referencing the business layer so I can reuse the Web methods.  My question is, do I have to decorate each class with DataContract and each property of the request with DataMember?

Currently, one of the classes is decorated with SerializableAttribute, XmlTypeAttribute, and XmlRootAttribute.  Do I need to remove these and add DataContract or do I can I add DataContract to it?  It is a .NET 2 app by the way.  The class also contains a bunch of private fields and public properties, do I need to decorate these with a DataMember attribute.  Is this even possible if it is using the .NET 2 framework?

The WCF Service is currently targeting .NET Framework 4.0.  A few of the methods need to still use the XmlSerializer, so does this mean I can just decorate the operation with [XmlSerializerFormat]?

Can you elaborate on not using any business objects on the service boundary? and what is DTO?

If possible, can you give an example?

Comment: Regarding XMLSerializer: yes. I'll edit my answer about DTOs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since .NET 3.5 SP1 the DataContractSerializer does not require the use of attributes (called POCO support). Although this gives you little control over the XML that is produced

However, if you already have an ASMX service you want to port then to maintain the same serialization you really want to use the XmlSerializer. You can wire this in in WCF using the [XmlSerializerFormat] attribute which can be applied at the service contract or individual operation level

**Edit: adding section on DTOs**

However, putting business objects on service boundaries causes potential issues:

1. You may be exposing unnecessary data that is purely part of your business rules
2. You tightly couple your service consumers to your business layers introducing fragility in their code and preventing you from refactoring freely

The idea of Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) is to create classes whose sole role in life is to manage the transition between the XML and object worlds. This also conforms to the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). The DTOs oinly expose the necessary data and act as a buffer between business changes and the wire format. Here is an example

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ICustomer
{
    [OperationContract]
    CustomerDTO GetCustomer(int id);
}

class CustomerService : ICustomer
{
    ICustomerRepository repo;
    public CustomerService (ICustomerRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public CustomerService()
        :this(new DBCustomerRepository())
    {

    }

    public CustomerDTO GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        Customer c = repo.GetCustomer(id);
        return new CustomerDTO
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Name = c.Name,
            AvailableBalance = c.Balance + c.CreditLimit,
        };
    }
}

class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public decimal CreditLimit { get; set; }      
}

[DataContract(Name="Customer")]
class CustomerDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal AvailableBalance { get; set; }
}
```

Using DTOs allows you to expose existing business functionality via services without having to make changes to that business functionality for purely technical reasons

The one issue people tend to baulk at with DTOs is the necessity of mapping between them and business objects. However, when you consider the advantages they bring I think it is a small price to pay and it is a price that can be heavily reduced by tools such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Richard, thanks so far. I have a huge existing ASMX service already.  I know the part about the XmlSerializer, but my main question was, all the classes that are used in the ASMX service, do they have to be decorated with the DataContract attribute now and do the fields and other properties have to be decorated with the DataMember attribute.

Comment: Not if you are on .NET 3.5 SP1 or later. The DataContractSerialzer will serialize public fields and properties of public classes via its POCO support. You can control the mapping from CLR to XML namespace using the [ContractNameSpace] attribute. As I said though, thats pretty much the only control you get without using the [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes

Comment: Richard, the ASMX service is in .NET 2.0 along with the business logic classes that the ASMX uses.

Comment: To use WCF you have to at least upgrade to .NET 3.0 (which IIRC is currently at SP1) - would uprading to .NET 3.5 (also SP1) be an issue?

Comment: Richard, upgrading the website to a 3.0 is a problem right now.  Currently, it is .NET 2.0. The classes that the asmx service uses were autogenerated with xsd.exe and these are the same classes that I am using in my wcf library.  Do I need to rewrite these classes in order for them to be used in the wcf library?

Comment: Ah ok - sorry I was talking at crossed purposes. The WCF service can use these classes and as long as the WCF service uses .NET 3.5 SP1 or later you do not need to change the classes.  A couple of points however: if you want the serialization to work the same for ASMX and WCF then you can make WCF use the XmlSerializer (see XmlSerializerFormat] attribute; I'd advise against using business objects on the service boundary - if you change them then you break the consumers of your service - create DTO classes purely to aid serialization and map to and from them to your business layer

Comment: I will update my post with a couple questions regarding your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

WCF uses the `DataContractSerializer` which is primarily based upon attributes like: `DataContract, DataMember, ServiceContract` and so forth. But it also supports `SerializableAttribute` amongst others. This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx document gives you all the insight you need.

So it might be that you don't need to refactor all your existing code but it aks some further investigation and testing ;)